# Confused about do while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

According to MDN, `do while loop` states that this is the syntax and do runs once despite the condition

do
statement
while (condition);

The following is my code

```
let mergeArr3 = (arr1 , arr2) => {
   let i = 1;
   do {
      console.log('hello') //prints hello 5 times
      i++;
   }
   while (i < 6 ) {
      console.log(i) //prints 6
      console.log('world') // prints world once
   }
   
}

mergeArr3(arr1 , arr2)
```

I am struggling to understand two things:

1. Why does `console.log(i)` print `6`  when 6 < 6 suppose to be evaluated to false and it shouldn't be running that line of code when i === 6.
2. `Do` is suppose to run once, but why is it running 5 times?

Comment: a: Because its while less than 6, so when it's 6 it ends.  b: because [1,2,3,4,5], yes there is 5 times here..   The interesting thing that you might have accidentally stumbled upon, is why do loops in computing code often start at 0,..  because < 6 starting at 0, is 6 iterations.  If you want 6 iterations but still start at 1, use <= 6.

Comment: The do loop runs "at least once", not "exactly once". It would also be clearer to you what's going on if you inserted semi-colons at the end of your lines of code. There should be one as follows: `while (i < 6 ); {`, for example, and the open brace is part of the next block of code.

Answer (score 3):

the "loop" part is only the block between `do` and `while`.

It's executed at least once, and **until the while condition is `falsy`**

The block you wrote after the while is just an independent block of code, that should be read like this for better clarity  :

```
   let i = 1;

   // loop do -- while
   do {
      console.log('hello') //prints hello 5 times
      i++;
   }
   while (i < 6) // if the condition here is true, execute the above block again.

   // this is just a legal block of code but completely unrelated to the loop.
   {
      console.log(i) //prints 6
      console.log('world') // prints world once
   }
```

So, the last block after the loop is executed when i *is not* less than 6, i.e. when i is exactly 6. This explains the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (i < 6 )
       {
          console.log(i) //prints 6
          console.log('world') // prints world once
       }
```

The part after while condition is never the part of do-while its just normal block with console inside. This will always be interpretes like below by JS or any language that supports do-while:

```
let mergeArr3 = (arr1 , arr2) => {
   let i = 1;
   do {
      console.log('hello') //prints hello 5 times
      i++;
   }
   while (i < 6 );
       {
          console.log(i) //prints 6
          console.log('world') // prints world once
       }
       
    }
```